# Ubuntu 15.10 5G WIFI issues

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 15.10

I currently have a dual-booted computer running Windows and Ubuntu. I also have the option of connecting to a 2.4Ghz and 5G network in both the Windows and Ubuntu menus. However, while 5G works in Windows, I am unable to successfully connect to 5G in Ubuntu. It can find the network, but it just tries for a bit and then gives up. On a possibly related note, my 2.4G connection drops quite frequently, and I sometimes have to restart it to get it going. I have already looked for some ideas online, but have struggled to find anything so far...

Ran the script as the commenter suggested, can be found at http://paste.ubuntu.com/14846878/

I am currently connected to What_the_Functor, and wish to connect to What_the_Functor 5G. This connection is possible on the same computer via Windows, but on Ubuntu, it can detect but not connect.

Connecting to 5G
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14851729/

Comment: Is there any more info I could provide that might be useful? I'm not familiar with diagnosing Ubuntu  problems :(

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: updated, lots of interesting WIFI names popped up..

Comment: Can you please try to associate the wireless adapter with a 5 GHz network and re-run the diagnostics? That would be the more interesting part.

Comment: just updated  :)

Comment: Looks good. DHCP seems to work over the 5 GHz wireless network, there's a default gateway. What's the issue?

Comment: It "connects", but there is no Internet access :(

Comment: Pilot6's answer is worth a try, but the way it looks the issue may be the network configuration and not the device driver. Can you please perform steps 2 and 3 of [this answer](/a/727470/175814) to debug the networking issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to internet by some other adapter and install a better driver.

Run in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Then reboot.